# Using WordPress Featured Image as CSS Background Image

Tags: php, wordpress, background-image

I'm trying to use the latest post featured image as a background image for a div on my homepage. Can anyone help with the php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_get_recent_posts() will return a single, most recently published post using the parameters below.

I recommend placing the style in a stylesheet.

```
/* Get Recent Post */
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
/* If Featured Image Set */
if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent_post[0]['ID']) ){
    /* Get Image */
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent_post[0]['ID']), 'full');
    /* Output Div with Image Set Inline, Use padding Top for Responsive Ratio Size */
    echo '
    <div class="featured-image-div" style="background-image:url('.$image[0].');"></div>
    <style>
    .featured-image-div{
        padding-top: calc( 450 / 800 * 100% );
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    </stle>    
    ';                           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately it did not work for me. I'm using a shortcode plugin so I pasted your code and added the shortcode but no image :( I must be missing something

Comment: What plugin are you using? (I presumed you were adding the code to a PHP template.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I'm using the plugin "Insert PHP Code Snippet" then using a text widget on the homepage with that shortcode if that makes sense.

Comment: Try the updated script. Since you're not already in the loop, the post ID will need to be retrieved and specified.

Comment: Sure thing, @Forrest! To 'close' the question, please mark my answer as your selected answer!